# Javascript Promise Logic Assistance

Tags: javascript, object, promise, logic

I'm having trouble creating an indicator for a promise to resolve. I have a function that I need to trigger 10 similar statements as follows:

```
if(x>someNum){
object['NewProperty']=someVal;
}
```

At the end of the function I'd like to return the object with all the added properties. Currently it returns undefined as I'm guessing the return happens before the if statements finish running. I know I need a promise but I can't think of a logical check I could have to indicate a 'resolve'. Here's what my current function is:

```
function addProperties(){
  const objectPromise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    if(x>someNum){
     object['NewProperty']=someVal;
    }
    if(x>someNum){
     object['NewProperty2']=someVal2;
    }
    if(x>someNum){
     object['NewProperty3']=someVal3;
    }
    resolve();
});
objectPromise.then(function(){return object});
}
```

It still returns undefined and I think it's because the resolve is triggered while other code is still running, any help on logic I could use to indicate a true resolve would be appreciated!

Comment: Your `addProperties` function doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: Why are you using a promise here at all? Nothing in this function is asynchronous.

Comment: my original function was function addProperties(){if(blah){addProperty};if(blah){addProperty};return object}. It kept coming back undefined. Did I mis-diagnose my problem?

Comment: Probably. Can you please [edit] your question to include the original code as a [mcve], complete with the call to the function and how you use the return value?

Comment: above comments all true - additionally don't you want to resolve(object) instead?